# How to identify the main peaks in data that contains multiple broad peaks

Tags: r, vector

I've got some data that looks like it contains 23 peaks. The x-axis is time and y-axis is peak. However, each peak is quite broad, including several smaller peaks. I'd like to remove the smaller peaks, so I'm just left with the time for each main peak.

I'd be very grateful for some help!

```
time <- c(1562, 1563, 1564, 1565, 1566, 1810, 1811, 1812, 1813, 1814, 
          2058, 2059, 2060, 2061, 2306, 2307, 2308, 2309, 2310, 2560, 2561, 
          2562, 2563, 2564, 3064, 3065, 3066, 3067, 3580, 3581, 3582, 3583, 
          3584, 4095, 4096, 4097, 4098, 4099, 4610, 4611, 4612, 4613, 4614, 
          5128, 5129, 5130, 5131, 5132, 5133, 5637, 5638, 5639, 5640, 5641, 
          5876, 5877, 5878, 5879, 5880, 5881, 5882, 6125, 6126, 6127, 6128, 
          6129, 6130, 6607, 6608, 6609, 6610, 6611, 6612, 6613, 7072, 7073, 
          7074, 7075, 7076, 7077, 7078, 7079, 7519, 7520, 7521, 7522, 7523, 
          7524, 7525, 7526, 7527, 7528, 7941, 7942, 7943, 7944, 7945, 7946, 
          7947, 7948, 7949, 8342, 8343, 8344, 8345, 8346, 8347, 8348, 8349, 
          8350, 8351, 8708, 8709, 8710, 8711, 8712, 8713, 8714, 8715, 8716, 
          8717, 8718, 9045, 9046, 9047, 9048, 9049, 9050, 9051, 9052, 9053, 
          9054, 9055, 9352, 9353, 9354, 9355, 9356, 9357, 9358, 9359, 9360, 
          9361, 9362, 9363, 9624, 9625, 9626, 9627, 9628, 9629, 9630, 9631, 
          9632, 9633, 9634, 9867, 9868, 9869, 9870, 9871, 9872, 9873, 9874, 
          9875, 9876)

peak <- c(509, 672, 758, 686, 584, 559, 727, 759, 688, 528, 562, 711, 
          768, 678, 644, 750, 822, 693, 531, 566, 738, 793, 730, 511, 587, 
          739, 761, 651, 579, 747, 768, 705, 544, 551, 687, 756, 749, 645, 
          564, 680, 724, 691, 596, 535, 625, 685, 689, 612, 512, 537, 616, 
          657, 653, 573, 506, 598, 675, 685, 668, 609, 515, 575, 656, 687, 
          678, 626, 533, 509, 587, 641, 680, 663, 602, 515, 505, 583, 646, 
          693, 696, 684, 630, 549, 500, 572, 637, 681, 725, 736, 736, 703, 
          649, 556, 568, 637, 682, 743, 765, 767, 709, 660, 587, 548, 622, 
          690, 761, 779, 764, 749, 694, 631, 525, 571, 646, 724, 788, 811, 
          834, 818, 776, 712, 616, 536, 556, 649, 738, 801, 857, 866, 837, 
          808, 718, 647, 568, 508, 605, 714, 823, 872, 917, 916, 890, 825, 
          742, 642, 543, 549, 656, 766, 851, 921, 947, 951, 892, 830, 730, 
          617, 586, 675, 760, 804, 816, 795, 740, 690, 613, 522)

data <- data.frame(time = time, peak = peak)

ggplot(data, aes(x=time, y=peak)) +
  geom_line()
```

[image]

ADDITIONAL QUESTION:
I've been trying to apply this to another data set and it picks out too many peaks. The new data contains a broad normal distribution. I'd like it to pick out just the very highest peak in this distribution, but as you can see from the image, it picks out every individual peak on either side. Is there a modification that can be made to the code to pick them out?

```
data2 <- data.frame(time = c(5001, 5002, 5003, 5004, 5005, 5006, 5007, 5008, 5009, 5010, 
                             5011, 5012, 5013, 5014, 5015, 5016, 5017, 5018, 5019, 5020, 5021, 
                             5022, 5023, 5024, 5025, 5026, 5027, 5028, 5029, 5030, 5031, 5032, 
                             5033, 5034, 5035, 5036, 5037, 5038, 5039, 5040, 5041, 5042, 5043, 
                             5044, 5045, 5046, 5047, 5048, 5049, 5050, 5051, 5052, 5053, 5054, 
                             5055, 5056, 5057, 5058, 5059, 5060, 5061, 5062, 5063, 5064, 5065, 
                             5066, 5067, 5068, 5069, 5070, 5071, 5072, 5073, 5074, 5075, 5076, 
                             5077, 5078, 5079, 5080, 5081, 5082, 5083, 5084, 5085, 5086, 5087, 
                             5088, 5089, 5090, 5091, 5092, 5093, 5094, 5095, 5096, 5097, 5098, 
                             5099, 5100, 5101, 5102, 5103, 5104, 5105, 5106, 5107, 5108, 5109, 
                             5110, 5111, 5112, 5113, 5114, 5115, 5116, 5117, 5118, 5119, 5120, 
                             5121, 5122, 5123, 5124, 5125, 5126, 5127, 5135, 5136, 5137, 5138, 
                             5139, 5140, 5141, 5142, 5143, 5144, 5145, 5146, 5147, 5148, 5149, 
                             5150, 5151, 5152, 5153, 5154, 5155, 5156, 5157, 5158, 5159, 5160, 
                             5161, 5162, 5163, 5164, 5165, 5166, 5167, 5168, 5169, 5170, 5171, 
                             5172, 5173, 5174, 5175, 5176, 5177, 5178, 5179, 5180, 5181, 5182, 
                             5183, 5184, 5185, 5186, 5187, 5188, 5189, 5190, 5191, 5192, 5193, 
                             5194, 5195, 5196, 5197, 5198, 5199, 5200, 5201, 5202, 5203, 5204, 
                             5205, 5206, 5207, 5208, 5209, 5210, 5211, 5212, 5213, 5214, 5215, 
                             5216, 5217, 5218, 5219, 5220, 5221, 5222, 5223, 5224, 5225, 5226, 
                             5227, 5228, 5229, 5230, 5231, 5232, 5233, 5234, 5235, 5236, 5237, 
                             5238, 5239, 5240, 5241, 5242, 5243, 5244, 5245, 5246, 5247, 5248, 
                             5249, 5250, 5251, 5252, 5253, 5254, 5255, 5256, 5257, 5258, 5259, 
                             5260, 5261, 5262, 5263, 5264, 5265, 5266, 5267, 5268, 5269, 5270, 
                             5271, 5272, 5273, 5274, 5275, 5276, 5277, 5278, 5279, 5280, 5281, 
                             5282, 5283, 5284, 5285, 5286, 5287, 5288, 5289, 5290, 5291, 5292, 
                             5293, 5294, 5295, 5296, 5297, 5298, 5299, 5300, 5301, 5302, 5303, 
                             5304, 5305, 5306, 5307, 5308, 5309, 5310, 5311, 5312, 5313, 5314, 
                             5315, 5316, 5317, 5318, 5319, 5320, 5321, 5322, 5323, 5324, 5325, 
                             5326, 5327, 5328, 5329, 5330, 5331, 5332, 5333, 5334, 5335, 5336, 
                             5337, 5338, 5339, 5340, 5341, 5342, 5343, 5344, 5345, 5346, 5347, 
                             5348, 5349, 5350, 5351, 5352, 5353, 5354, 5355, 5356, 5357, 5358, 
                             5359, 5360, 5361, 5362, 5363, 5364, 5365, 5366, 5367, 5368, 5369, 
                             5370, 5371, 5372, 5373, 5374, 5375, 5376, 5377, 5378, 5379, 5380, 
                             5381, 5382, 5383, 5384, 5385, 5386, 5387, 5388, 5389, 5390, 5391, 
                             5392, 5393, 5394, 5395, 5396, 5397, 5398, 5399, 5400, 5401, 5402, 
                             5403, 5404, 5405, 5406, 5407, 5408, 5409, 5410, 5411, 5412, 5413, 
                             5414, 5415, 5416, 5417, 5418, 5419, 5420, 5421, 5422, 5423, 5424, 
                             5425, 5426, 5427, 5428, 5429, 5430, 5431, 5432, 5433, 5434, 5435, 
                             5436, 5437, 5438, 5439, 5440, 5441, 5442, 5443, 5444, 5445, 5446, 
                             5447, 5448, 5449, 5450, 5451, 5452, 5453, 5454, 5455, 5456, 5457, 
                             5458, 5459, 5460, 5461, 5462, 5463, 5464, 5465, 5466, 5467, 5468, 
                             5469, 5470, 5471, 5472, 5473, 5474, 5475, 5476, 5477, 5478, 5479, 
                             5480, 5481, 5482, 5483, 5484, 5485, 5486, 5487, 5488, 5489, 5490, 
                             5491, 5492, 5493, 5494, 5495, 5496, 5497, 5498, 5499, 5500, 5501, 
                             5502, 5503, 5504, 5505, 5506, 5507, 5508, 5509, 5510, 5511, 5512, 
                             5513, 5514, 5515, 5516, 5517, 5518, 5519, 5520, 5521, 5522, 5523, 
                             5524, 5525, 5526, 5527, 5528, 5529, 5530, 5531, 5532, 5533, 5534, 
                             5535, 5536, 5537, 5538, 5539, 5540, 5541, 5542, 5543, 5544, 5545, 
                             5546, 5547, 5548, 5549, 5550, 5551, 5552, 5553, 5554, 5555, 5556, 
                             5557, 5558, 5559, 5560, 5561, 5562, 5563, 5564, 5565, 5566, 5567, 
                             5568, 5569, 5570, 5571, 5572, 5573, 5574, 5575, 5576, 5577, 5578, 
                             5579, 5580, 5581, 5582, 5583, 5584, 5585, 5586, 5587, 5588, 5589, 
                             5590, 5591, 5592, 5593, 5594, 5595, 5596, 5597, 5598, 5599, 5600, 
                             5601, 5602, 5603, 5604, 5605, 5606, 5607, 5608, 5609, 5610, 5611, 
                             5612, 5613, 5614, 5615, 5616, 5617, 5618, 5619, 5620, 5621, 5622, 
                             5623, 5624, 5625, 5626, 5627, 5628, 5629, 5630, 5631, 5632, 5633, 
                             5634, 5635, 5636, 5637, 5638, 5639, 5640, 5641, 5642, 5643, 5644, 
                             5645, 5646, 5647, 5648, 5649, 5650, 5651, 5652, 5653, 5654, 5655, 
                             5656, 5657, 5658, 5659, 5660, 5661, 5662, 5663, 5664, 5665, 5666, 
                             5667, 5668, 5669, 5670, 5671, 5672, 5673, 5674, 5675, 5676, 5677, 
                             5678, 5679, 5680, 5681, 5682, 5683, 5684, 5685, 5686, 5687, 5688, 
                             5689, 5690, 5691, 5692, 5693, 5694, 5695, 5696, 5697, 5698, 5699, 
                             5700, 5701, 5702, 5703, 5704, 5705, 5706, 5707, 5708, 5709, 5710, 
                             5711, 5712, 5713, 5714, 5715, 5716, 5717, 5718, 5719, 5720, 5721, 
                             5722, 5723, 5724, 5725, 5726, 5727, 5728, 5729, 5730, 5731, 5732, 
                             5733, 5734, 5735, 5736, 5737, 5738, 5739, 5740, 5741, 5742, 5743, 
                             5744, 5745, 5746, 5747, 5748, 5749, 5750, 5751, 5752, 5753, 5754, 
                             5755, 5756, 5757, 5758, 5759, 5760, 5761, 5762, 5763, 5764, 5765, 
                             5766, 5767, 5768, 5769, 5770, 5771, 5772, 5773, 5774, 5775, 5776, 
                             5777, 5778, 5779, 5780, 5781, 5782, 5783, 5784, 5785, 5786, 5787, 
                             5788, 5789, 5790, 5791, 5792, 5793, 5794, 5795, 5796, 5797, 5798, 
                             5799, 5800, 5801, 5802, 5803, 5804, 5805, 5806, 5807, 5808, 5809, 
                             5810, 5811, 5812, 5813, 5814, 5815, 5816, 5817, 5818, 5819, 5820, 
                             5821, 5822, 5823, 5824, 5825, 5826, 5827, 5828, 5829, 5830, 5831, 
                             5832, 5833, 5834, 5835, 5836, 5837, 5838, 5839, 5840, 5841, 5842, 
                             5843, 5844, 5845, 5846, 5847, 5848, 5849, 5850, 5851, 5852, 5853, 
                             5854, 5855, 5856, 5857, 5858, 5859, 5860, 5861, 5862, 5863, 5864, 
                             5865, 5866, 5867, 5868, 5869, 5870, 5871, 5872, 5873, 5874, 5875, 
                             5876, 5885, 5886, 5887, 5888, 5889, 5890, 5891, 5892, 5893, 5894, 
                             5895, 5896, 5897, 5898, 5899, 5900, 5901, 5902, 5903, 5904, 5905, 
                             5906, 5907, 5908, 5909, 5910, 5911, 5912, 5913, 5914, 5915, 5916, 
                             5917, 5918, 5919, 5920, 5921, 5922, 5923, 5924, 5925, 5926, 5927, 
                             5928, 5929, 5930, 5931, 5932, 5933, 5934, 5935, 5936, 5937, 5938, 
                             5939, 5940, 5941, 5942, 5943, 5944, 5945, 5946, 5947, 5948, 5949, 
                             5950, 5951, 5952, 5953, 5954, 5955, 5956, 5957, 5958, 5959, 5960, 
                             5961, 5962, 5963, 5964, 5965, 5966, 5967, 5968, 5969, 5970, 5971, 
                             5972, 5973, 5974, 5975, 5976, 5977, 5978, 5979, 5980, 5981, 5982, 
                             5983, 5984, 5985, 5986, 5987, 5988, 5989, 5990, 5991, 5992, 5993, 
                             5994, 5995, 5996, 5997, 5998, 5999),
                    peak = c(245, 236, 220, 189, 173, 154, 142, 124, 118, 105, 107, 99, 
                             100, 98, 111, 116, 115, 126, 129, 128, 128, 132, 134, 145, 158, 
                             170, 188, 207, 225, 242, 237, 229, 211, 189, 173, 151, 131, 116, 
                             113, 98, 105, 96, 101, 112, 106, 112, 113, 111, 124, 131, 127, 
                             130, 137, 149, 146, 164, 184, 210, 228, 239, 228, 225, 217, 185, 
                             168, 149, 140, 126, 110, 101, 104, 100, 102, 103, 109, 105, 109, 
                             114, 117, 122, 128, 119, 130, 142, 148, 166, 182, 204, 226, 235, 
                             247, 226, 224, 193, 174, 153, 137, 124, 119, 110, 99, 105, 96, 
                             98, 102, 116, 122, 117, 116, 132, 123, 130, 139, 138, 145, 166, 
                             182, 191, 215, 221, 212, 207, 186, 153, 112, 66, 8, 27, 68, 86, 
                             113, 125, 130, 139, 148, 153, 159, 178, 188, 213, 230, 249, 259, 
                             246, 234, 219, 197, 175, 151, 133, 126, 117, 122, 120, 115, 109, 
                             115, 116, 125, 133, 141, 139, 142, 148, 147, 155, 170, 178, 203, 
                             226, 254, 259, 273, 257, 249, 221, 191, 173, 152, 145, 130, 121, 
                             127, 118, 121, 119, 124, 130, 136, 146, 144, 154, 166, 155, 163, 
                             168, 190, 215, 223, 252, 273, 282, 275, 268, 237, 220, 191, 168, 
                             159, 140, 137, 130, 122, 131, 120, 134, 132, 134, 137, 142, 151, 
                             153, 164, 162, 176, 190, 196, 217, 243, 266, 271, 262, 257, 237, 
                             214, 187, 169, 147, 138, 126, 118, 116, 114, 117, 116, 123, 123, 
                             123, 129, 140, 146, 152, 156, 166, 178, 185, 209, 241, 264, 264, 
                             261, 262, 232, 204, 178, 162, 140, 125, 117, 110, 112, 103, 98, 
                             105, 108, 116, 117, 130, 128, 142, 135, 138, 149, 161, 169, 193, 
                             222, 244, 256, 265, 246, 222, 201, 174, 147, 130, 125, 110, 102, 
                             97, 95, 90, 98, 99, 107, 117, 115, 119, 128, 131, 137, 135, 144, 
                             173, 188, 209, 232, 251, 251, 244, 217, 190, 162, 144, 122, 116, 
                             103, 94, 87, 88, 92, 97, 101, 97, 98, 108, 121, 122, 118, 128, 
                             132, 144, 162, 180, 209, 230, 246, 233, 230, 218, 187, 159, 125, 
                             124, 105, 92, 89, 84, 81, 85, 76, 78, 92, 92, 102, 102, 109, 
                             115, 126, 134, 137, 164, 179, 208, 227, 241, 258, 247, 223, 203, 
                             173, 140, 121, 111, 94, 98, 85, 87, 89, 91, 84, 91, 106, 103, 
                             107, 111, 123, 126, 142, 150, 166, 194, 221, 242, 247, 254, 237, 
                             229, 194, 170, 140, 130, 110, 94, 85, 84, 84, 79, 82, 88, 89, 
                             100, 108, 111, 114, 121, 122, 142, 149, 175, 198, 236, 252, 268, 
                             279, 257, 232, 194, 170, 151, 127, 108, 104, 95, 91, 81, 83, 
                             94, 92, 96, 106, 111, 122, 115, 131, 142, 152, 167, 183, 222, 
                             248, 282, 290, 296, 279, 249, 226, 190, 163, 136, 116, 109, 93, 
                             95, 92, 86, 86, 91, 108, 109, 120, 121, 131, 140, 141, 157, 187, 
                             216, 240, 276, 311, 319, 333, 309, 281, 237, 203, 167, 134, 123, 
                             112, 104, 92, 95, 99, 103, 112, 110, 114, 128, 138, 140, 161, 
                             180, 193, 223, 242, 276, 317, 352, 372, 383, 354, 318, 285, 222, 
                             190, 163, 144, 124, 114, 100, 98, 107, 105, 117, 121, 133, 144, 
                             166, 176, 185, 199, 225, 268, 306, 348, 384, 439, 466, 463, 427, 
                             392, 329, 274, 221, 181, 161, 141, 131, 123, 127, 128, 131, 138, 
                             147, 163, 173, 188, 208, 221, 242, 294, 338, 380, 468, 518, 568, 
                             596, 604, 554, 488, 403, 336, 275, 229, 182, 159, 141, 143, 140, 
                             143, 160, 163, 183, 204, 230, 241, 244, 281, 316, 382, 448, 515, 
                             624, 720, 790, 840, 790, 709, 616, 505, 412, 329, 267, 218, 186, 
                             166, 155, 148, 158, 171, 183, 204, 211, 230, 243, 235, 268, 280, 
                             315, 395, 525, 690, 881, 986, 1037, 1002, 930, 790, 668, 556, 
                             444, 335, 276, 236, 218, 201, 201, 216, 227, 257, 290, 331, 368, 
                             401, 451, 525, 599, 693, 823, 988, 1160, 1354, 1466, 1468, 1399, 
                             1220, 1016, 824, 648, 501, 402, 326, 273, 253, 233, 235, 266, 
                             271, 300, 359, 380, 422, 462, 532, 592, 703, 886, 1062, 1253, 
                             1444, 1588, 1701, 1691, 1551, 1372, 1141, 929, 713, 563, 445, 
                             362, 305, 258, 245, 240, 254, 280, 319, 348, 394, 416, 478, 537, 
                             608, 717, 829, 989, 1197, 1426, 1551, 1579, 1563, 1447, 1244, 
                             1026, 801, 638, 500, 379, 303, 265, 230, 221, 202, 203, 225, 
                             246, 289, 303, 327, 374, 396, 462, 539, 625, 744, 899, 1017, 
                             1094, 1138, 1058, 946, 832, 677, 543, 415, 337, 272, 230, 200, 
                             182, 173, 170, 173, 174, 196, 208, 218, 236, 250, 280, 324, 364, 
                             424, 505, 567, 627, 649, 660, 626, 568, 484, 400, 325, 276, 222, 
                             185, 159, 143, 136, 129, 130, 131, 135, 142, 153, 162, 178, 191, 
                             208, 228, 245, 285, 317, 347, 378, 397, 380, 367, 323, 288, 242, 
                             202, 171, 151, 130, 112, 112, 103, 101, 103, 100, 113, 119, 118, 
                             127, 135, 143, 155, 158, 177, 195, 207, 226, 247, 253, 244, 224, 
                             201, 177, 156, 134, 118, 113, 102, 100, 90, 88, 84, 94, 87, 94, 
                             102, 103, 101, 108, 107, 121, 120, 131, 136, 127, 135, 122, 91, 
                             41, 3, 5, 32, 48, 50, 61, 71, 75, 80, 87, 90, 98, 108, 107, 127, 
                             136, 139, 145, 149, 138, 139, 129, 117, 106, 94, 91, 84, 74, 
                             75, 70, 71, 74, 72, 74, 81, 78, 87, 85, 81, 91, 93, 98, 102, 
                             122, 120, 127, 129, 126, 133, 113, 103, 97, 90, 85, 75, 79, 69, 
                             63, 65, 68, 68, 71, 74, 73, 78, 71, 81, 78, 87, 92, 104, 109, 
                             118, 115, 130, 121, 122, 111, 97, 89, 87, 85, 75, 71, 70, 62, 
                             65, 60, 69, 60, 68, 64, 66, 70, 81, 82, 85, 89, 90, 96, 105, 
                             122, 115, 126, 114, 119, 105, 96, 94, 85, 72, 68, 62, 70, 58, 
                             59))

blue.peaks <- tibble(time = data2$time, value = data2$peak)
blue.peaks <- blue.peaks %>% mutate(left_v = c(0.01, diff(value)),
                                    right_v = -lead(left_v, default = -0.01),
                                    is_peak = if_else(left_v > 0 & right_v >= 0, TRUE, FALSE))
data2$keep <- blue.peaks$is_peak
data2$keep <- ifelse(data2$keep == TRUE, data2$peak, NA)

ggplot(data2, aes(x=time, y=peak)) +
  geom_col() +
  geom_point(aes(x=time, y=keep))
```

[image]

Comment: Can u describe what 'small' or 'main' peaks are?

Comment: Basically each of the 23 peaks isn’t a single line, it has some width. I just want a single value of x for each peak, and that will be the tallest value of y in that region of x

Comment: did you try [findpeaks](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/pracma/versions/1.9.9/topics/findpeaks)? It would also useful to provide data directly with dput(red.corr$peak) instead of console output.

Comment: Yes, but I couldn’t get it working. I’m back at the computer in an hour and will output the data directly, thanks

Comment: I've updated it to include the data directly. I've also included a plot to show the data. It shows 23 clear "spikes". I'd like to know the x coordinates of the very peak of each of those spikes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**BEFORE EDIT**

data (only peak values):

```
peak <- c(
 509, 672 ,758, 686 ,584, 559, 727, 759, 688, 528, 562, 711, 768, 678, 644, 750, 822, 693, 531, 566, 738, 793, 730, 511, 587 ,739, 761, 651, 579,
 747, 768, 705, 544, 551, 687, 756, 749, 645, 564, 680, 724, 691, 596, 535, 625, 685, 689, 612, 512, 537, 616, 657, 653 ,573, 506, 598, 675, 685,
668, 609 ,515, 575, 656, 687, 678, 626, 533, 509, 587, 641, 680, 663, 602, 515 ,505, 583, 646, 693, 696, 684, 630, 549, 500 ,572, 637, 681, 725,
 736 ,736, 703, 649, 556, 568, 637, 682, 743, 765, 767, 709, 660, 587, 548, 622, 690, 761, 779, 764, 749, 694, 631 ,525 ,571 ,646, 724, 788, 811,
 834, 818, 776, 712, 616, 536, 556, 649, 738, 801, 857, 866, 837, 808, 718 ,647 ,568, 508, 605, 714, 823, 872, 917 ,916, 890 ,825, 742, 642, 543,
 549, 656, 766, 851, 921, 947, 951, 892, 830, 730, 617, 586, 675, 760, 804, 816 ,795, 740, 690, 613, 522)
```

code:

```
peak_data <- tibble(
  value = peak
)

peak_data <- peak_data %>%
  mutate(
    left_v = c(0.01, diff(value)),
    right_v = -lead(left_v, default = -0.01),
    peak = if_else(
      (left_v > 0 & right_v >= 0) | (left_v >= 0 & right_v > 0), TRUE, FALSE
    )
  ) %>%
  filter(peak == TRUE) %>%
  select(-left_v, -right_v, -peak)
```

I've put some postive number (0.01) for cheking if edges are peaks. I've got 24 peaks (local max) from this code:

```
peak_data %>% nrow()
[1] 24
```

I'm still not exactly sure what you mean by peak, for example vector:

```
x <- c(5, 6, 6, 4)
```

has 2 peaks in my code. Its easy to adapt it to have 0 peaks with change:

```
(left_v > 0 & right_v >= 0) | (left_v >= 0 & right_v > 0)
```

to:

```
left_v > 0 & right_v > 0
```

then I get 22 peaks. Or you can count it as 1 by putting one of:

```
left_v >= 0 & right_v > 0
left_v > 0 & right_v >= 0
```

depending what side you want to count for 23 peaks.

**AFTER EDIT AND COMMENT**

```
peak_data <- tibble(
  peak = peak,
  time = time
)

peak_data <- peak_data %>%
  mutate(
    left_v = c(0.01, diff(peak)),
    right_v = -lead(left_v, default = -0.01),
    is_peak = if_else(
      left_v > 0 & right_v >= 0, TRUE, FALSE
    )
  ) %>%
  filter(is_peak == TRUE) %>%
  select(peak, time)
```

gives peaks and peaks time.

Comment: Thanks, but I can't see how you can get the x coordinates (time) for each peak? I've updated above with the plot I see which has 23 peaks ("spikes") in the data. What I need ideally is to have the "data" data frame subset so it only includes the spikes. That way I can find out the x coordinates (time) of each spike

Comment: Ah, I see the problem, for some reason your function is calling a peak at 7524 and at 7525. I think this is because both have a peak of 736. Would it be possible to build into the function that if there are two immediately adjacent ones of the same peak height that it takes the smaller (lower x value) of the two?

Comment: just put time as variable in data.frame(I didnt put it cos I had to manualy put data in right format so I've put only peaks cos all calculation is done only on that variable) `peak_data <- tibble(value = peak, time = time)`. It is possible I've put 3 situations -use `left_v > 0 & right_v >= 0` as condition in `if_else`

Comment: Thanks again. I've tried applying your solution to a new data set and it seems to pick out too many peaks. Is there a way to make it more stringent? I've added to the question above with the details

Comment: @Mike it should be possible, but again it seems that definition of peak changes from case to case